# Epson Image scanning in Debian

Tags: linux, ubuntu, scanning

I couldn't get my Epson XP-430 to work on an Ubuntu 16.04 based system.

Saw errors like:

`Could not send command to scanner`

`no devices found`

And this is after installing all the official drivers here:

http://support.epson.net/linux/en/imagescanv3.php?version=1.3.28

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that you need to add the scanner into the config manually, especially if it is connected via network.

CTI on the Linux Mint forums was especially helpful:

```
edit the file /etc/sane.d/epkowa.con and set/add the line
net <your epson LAN address>
e.g. in my case
net 192.168.1.137
```

src: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=232860